# How do I access the Sharebuilder UserID in SQL Server Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to pull the Sharepoint UserID out so I can use it as a parameter to control what the user of a dashboard can see.  I have tried setting up a UserID parameter using the built-in field UserID and used that in a query to get a list of personnel but Report Builder gives me an error that I am trying to use a forward reference.  How can I access the UserID in such a way that I can use to pull up the user's information from a SQL Server database?  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the code you tried so far.

Comment: I haven't used any actual code yet.  I have been trying to set up various parameters in Report Builder.  What I am having a hard time figuring out is if use a placeholder with the Fields(Personnel).UserID it gives me what I need but when I set up a parameter using the Personnel.UserID value it gives me the first UserID in the dataset and I would think that it should give the same value both ways.

Comment: I fixed this problem by moving my UserID parameter to the top of my parameter list.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by moving my UserID parameter to the top of my parameter list. Thanks